# Multivariate Gaussian Distribution Scipy

Tags: python, machine-learning, scipy

I have a two dimensional data, and I fit that data to Gaussian distribution as follows :-

```
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal

dataset = np.array([
    [3, 3],
    [3, 2],
    [4, 1],
    [4, 2],
    [4, 3],
    [4, 4],
    [5, 2],
    [5, 3]
])

mu = np.mean(dataset, axis=0)

sigma = np.cov(dataset.T)

p = multivariate_normal(mean=mu, cov=sigma)

print("pdf for [10, 10] : ", p.pdf(np.array([10, 10])))

print("pdf for [5, 1] : ", p.pdf(np.array([5, 1])))
```

My question :-

How do I accurately predict which dataset will belong to this distribution, should I used the Z score as a meausre, or is there some other way to do the same. Currently I am using zscore val as follows :-

```
from scipy.stats import zscore

def getZScore(org_vals, new_val):
    org_vals.append(new_val)
    scores = zscore(org_vals)
    return scores[-1]

pdfValsForTrainData = [p.pdf(item) for item in dataset]

pdfVal = p.pdf(np.array([10, 10]))

zScoreVal = getZScore(pdfValsForTrainData, pdfVal)

print("z score for [10, 10] : ", zScoreVal)
```

The greater the deviation the more likelihood it does not belong to this distribution

Is there any way to identify the epsilon value for distribution without any manual intervention ?

Comment: As this is more an algorithmic question, you might get better answers on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Not sure if I understood what you're trying to achieve but maybe the [Kolmogorov–Smirnov test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov–Smirnov_test) would be useful? There's a scipy implementation [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.kstest.html) and [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ks_2samp.html).